# dialogue with checkbox the passingin check values to empty select box

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysqli

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                .html('<form id="myform" action=""><input type="checkbox"   id="completeCheck" name="completeCheck" value="truck" />Complete check<br /><input type="checkbox" name="view" value="Car" /> View report <br /><input type="checkbox" name="consist" value="van" />Consistency check<br /><input type="checkbox" name="other" value="bike" />Other checks<br /><input type="checkbox" name="keyCheck" value="scooter" />Key check<br /><input type="checkbox" name="compareCheck" value="skate" />Compare check<br /></form>')
                .dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    title: 'Data check',
                    buttons: {
                        "Submit Form": function() {
                            $('form#myform').submit();
                        },
                        "Cancel": function() {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    }
                });

            $('#createNew').click(function() {
                $dialog.dialog('open');
                // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
                return false;
            });

            $('form#myform').submit(function() {
                $(this).find(':checkbox').each(function() {
                    if (this.checked) {
                        //alert(this.value + ' is checked');

                        var sel = $('<select>').appendTo('body');
                        sel.append($("<option>").attr('value', this.value).text(this.name));

                    } else
                        alert(this.name + ' is not checked');
                });
                $dialog.dialog('close');
            });


        });
    </script>
    <a id="createNew" href="#">open</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Having a pop-up box then within that popup box, you would have check boxes when you select those check boxes they populate an empty select box with the items you selected in the popup box . Then as you select those items one by one a input box appears for each item selected. Then you would have to pass those items that are populated in the select box to the database along with the corresponding input fields.

I am having issues with getting the values from the checkbox dialogue to populate to the select box. It is passing through the url and also reloading the page. Also would like to pass all the values from the select box to the mysql database.

Comment: So what exactly is the question here? where are you stuck? (a particular point?)

Comment: i have updated the post.

Comment: you need each checkbox as individual select box ?

Comment: @ Supun Praneeth no they should go into one select box

Comment: Hi @TripplexPC-Tech. I don't know what you are trying to achieve. If you want to send selected values from the dialog box to database, then there is no need to create individual dropdowns. 

If you want dropdowns. Please check the code here [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/xuduropaho/edit?html,output). The thing here is it will not send value to `php` file because there is no `name` attr for `select`.

Comment: the dropdown is very important. Because i want the user to select options from the dropdown to the generate an input field for them to enter values corresponding to their selection from the dropdown. but that is after they are presented with the dialogue with checkboxes

Comment: I think this is what you are excepting [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/heyuxujuca/1/edit?html,output). If you make ajax call or form submit. Then in PHP side, you can read values with name `checkbox_values`

Comment: thanks much @ Sathvik Chinnu

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
        .html('<form id="myform" action=""><input type="checkbox"   id="completeCheck" name="completeCheck" value="truck" />Complete check<br /><input type="checkbox" name="view" value="Car" /> View report <br /><input type="checkbox" name="consist" value="van" />Consistency check<br /><input type="checkbox" name="other" value="bike" />Other checks<br /><input type="checkbox" name="keyCheck" value="scooter" />Key check<br /><input type="checkbox" name="compareCheck" value="skate" />Compare check<br /></form>')
        .dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          title: 'Data check',
          buttons: {
            "Submit Form": function() {
              $('form#myform').submit();
            },
            "Cancel": function() {
              $(this).dialog("close");
            }
          }
        });
      $('#createNew').click(function() {
        $dialog.dialog('open');
        // prevent the default action, e.g., following a link
        return false;
      });
      $('form#myform').submit(function(e) {
        var sel = $('<select>').appendTo('body');
        $(this).find(':checkbox').each(function() {
          if (this.checked) {            
            sel.append($("<option>").attr('value', this.value).text(this.name));
          } else {
            alert(this.name + ' is not checked');
          }
        });
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'url',
          data: $(this).serialize()
        });
        $dialog.dialog('close');
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    });
  </script>

  <a id="createNew" href="#">open</a>

</body>

</html>
```

[codepen](https://codepen.io/spmsupun/pen/bKLpdL)

Comment: now i just need to find out how to match the corresponding input boxes to it based on the selection

Comment: Sorry, i don't get it

Comment: @ Supun Praneeth i need to generate input fields based on the selection from the dropdown box now so i can pass all the values from the select box with the corresponding  options. So if i select completeCheck from the select box an input field should appear then i type in what every value related to it in the input field then when i select view from the dropdown  an input box appear and so on. then i would pass all items in the select box to the database along with the corresponding input fields.

Comment: have a problem its when i click open it shows the item i checked but if i check a new item and submit again it duplicates the previous ones.

Comment: i am trying to accomplish what i mention, but having issues. So example: in the select box i have: Truck, Car, Bike. if i go back and check some other checkboxes i get: Truck, Car, Bike, Truck, Car, Bike, Scooter.  AS you can see the options in the select box has duplicates. I do not want this. Also how the code is now its creting new select box if i go back and check the checkboxes. Also do not want that.